# I need to delete thumb in input type range

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I need to remove the thumb from the progress bar.
I have tried several options to do this but I can't get it to disappear.
The idea is that the progress bar moves forward without the thumb, simply that the colour moves as it advances with the Progress variable.

Here are images of what it looks like now and how it should look like.[image]

Here is the code:

```
const MusicPlayer = ({ track }: Props) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio(track.preview));
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleCanPlay = () => {
      setIsPlaying(true);
      audio.play();
    };

    const handleEnded = () => {
      setIsPlaying(false);
      setProgress(0);
    };

    const handleTimeUpdate = () => {
      setCurrentTime(audio.currentTime);
      setProgress((audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100);
    };

    audio.addEventListener("canplay", handleCanPlay);
    audio.addEventListener("ended", handleEnded);
    audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeUpdate);

    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener("canplay", handleCanPlay);
      audio.removeEventListener("ended", handleEnded);
      audio.removeEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeUpdate);
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    };
  }, [track.preview, audio, setIsPlaying]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.src = track.preview;
  }, [track.preview, audio]);

  const togglePlay = () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  };

  return (
    <div className="music-player-container" onClick={togglePlay}>
      <div className="left">
        <img
          src={track.album.cover_medium}
          alt="Album Cover"
          className="album-cover"
        />
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="album-title">{track.title}</p>
          <p className="album-subtitle">{track.artist.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="center">
        <button>{isPlaying ? "▌▌" : "▶"}</button>
        <div className="bar-container">
          <label>{convertSecondsToMinutes(Math.floor(currentTime))}</label>
          <input
            type="range"
            value={progress}
            max={100}
            readOnly
            className="bar-progress"
            style={{
              background: `linear-gradient(to right, #EF5466 ${progress}%, #0000000D ${progress}%)`,
            }}
          />
          <label>{convertSecondsToMinutes(track.duration)}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MusicPlayer;


.bar-progress {
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 560px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 6px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.bar-progress::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a range input for this - and not the [`progress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element ...?

Comment: I didn't know it... :/

Comment: There's also the [`<meter>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter) element, depending on what you're trying to show; but CBroe's probably right that the `<progress>` is probably the right choice.

Comment: Thank you very much.
The thumb has indeed been removed, although now it is showing me the values of the bar, inside it. Is there any property to hide it?

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-style-a-progress-bar-using-css

Comment: @TemaniAfif: thanks for the link, I do enjoy your articles (though the `border-image` article on Smashing Magazine *did* (kinda) break parts of my brain).

Answer (score 1):

add **visibility:hidden** in **::-webkit-slider-thumb** and **::-moz-range-thumb** pseudo-class:

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```